# Problem with graphql API fetching every milisecond

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, graphql

I was using a typescript then I wanted to switch to .jsx because I didn't used ts too much. I fixed everything and now I run the create react app and added my files. Everything works; I expect one API call that calls every second, problem is in `useEffect` that calls every time when it sees state. State doesn't need to change its calls anyway. I also used the apollo client but still nothing. I tried to put `console.log` in `useEffect`. Sometimes I can see it rendering every time, sometimes I can't. In  fetch function that fetches data, I can see console log every millisecond. Here's my code:

Also when I comment `setProducts` and `setProductsData` it fetches normally but doesn't update the state.

FilterContainer.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { TfiReload } from "react-icons/tfi";
import "animate.css";
import { AiOutlineSearch, AiOutlineInsertRowAbove } from "react-icons/ai";
import {
  BsEmojiFrown,
  BsFillFilterCircleFill,
  BsFilterCircle,
  BsReverseListColumnsReverse,
} from "react-icons/bs";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";
import "./FilterContainer.scss";
import Category from "../Category/Category";
import Product from "../Product/Product";
import Pagination from "../Pagination/Pagination";
import { fetchProducts } from "../../fetch/GlobalApis/products";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../Loader/Loader";

import { fetchReviews } from "../../fetch/GlobalApis/reviews";

function FilterContainer() {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(12);
  const [openFilter, setOpenFilter] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [productsAlign, setProductsAlign] = useState(false);
  const [productTypes, setProductTypes] = useState([]);
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);
  const [href, setHref] = useState("");
  const filterCategory = useRef();

  // Set lower itemsPerPage value on mobile devices
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 576 });
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("");
  const loader = useSelector((state) => state.api.loader);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.api.jwt);

  const url = useSelector((state) => state.navbar.url);

  const [reviewData, setReviewData] = useState([]);

  async function getProductData() {
    const data = await fetchProducts(dispatch, setProducts, setProductsData);
    console.log(productsData, products);
    setCategories();
  }

  // console.log(products);
  async function getReviewData() {
    const response = await fetchReviews(dispatch);

    setReviewData(response);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductData();
    console.log("work");
    getReviewData();
  }, []);
  function setCategories() {
    // Get all product types
    let pt = productsData?.map((product) => ({
      category: product.node.productType.split(",")[0],
      type: product.node.productType.split(",")[1].trim(),
    }));

    let mergedCategories = pt.reduce((acc, product) => {
      const existingCategory = acc.find(
        (category) => category.category === product.category
      );

      if (existingCategory) {
        existingCategory.types.push(product.type);
      } else {
        acc.push({ category: product.category, types: [product.type] });
      }

      return acc;
    }, []);

    setProductTypes(mergedCategories);
  }

  // Update the URL query parameter when sortBy state changes

  function handleSearch(event) {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const query = event?.target?.value?.toLowerCase();

    queryParams.set("search", query); // update "search" parameter with the value of query
    let newUrl = "";
    if (queryParams.toString()) {
      newUrl = `${window.location.pathname}?${queryParams.toString()}`;
    } else {
      newUrl = `${window.location.pathname}`;
    }

    window.history.pushState({}, "", newUrl);

    setHref(window.location.href);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let filteredProducts = [...productsData]; // create a new array with the contents of productsData

    if (queryParams.get("search")) {
      let query = queryParams.get("search");

      filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter((product) => {
        return (
          product.node.title.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||
          product.node.description.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||
          product.node.productType.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||
          product.node.tags.join(" ").toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
      });
    }
    if (queryParams.get("sort")) {
      filteredProducts = filteredProducts.sort((a, b) => {
        if (queryParams.get("sort") === "low-to-high") {
          return (
            a.node.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount -
            b.node.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount
          );
        } else if (queryParams.get("sort") === "high-to-low") {
          return (
            b.node.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount -
            a.node.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount
          );
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
    }
    if (queryParams.get("category")) {
      const query = queryParams.get("category").split("+"); // convert query string to array

      filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter((product) => {
        // use some() to check if product tags match any of the query values
        return query.some((tag) =>
          product.node.productType
            .toLowerCase()
            .split(" ")[1]
            .includes(tag.toLowerCase())
        );
      });
    }

    setProducts(filteredProducts);
  }, [href, url]); // add href variable to the dependency array

  function handleSortChange(event) {
    setSortBy(event?.target?.value);
  }

  function resetHandle() {
    const newUrl = window.location.pathname;
    window.history.pushState({}, "", newUrl);
    getProductData();
    setProducts(productsData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMobile) {
      setItemsPerPage(6);
    } else {
      setItemsPerPage(12);
    }
  }, [isMobile]);

  const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  const [priceOpened, setPriceOpened] = useState(false);

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(products?.length / itemsPerPage);
  const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
  const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
  const currentProducts = products?.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

  return (
    <div className="filter">
      {loader ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div
            style={
              openFilter
                ? {
                    height: `${
                      Math.ceil(productTypes?.length / 2) * 130 + 250
                    }px`,
                  }
                : { height: "40px" }
            }
            className={
              openFilter
                ? "filter__header filter__header--open "
                : "filter__header"
            }
          >
            <div
              className="filter__header__mobile "
              onClick={() => setOpenFilter((prev) => !prev)}
            >
              <h3>Filter </h3>

              {openFilter ? (
                <BsFillFilterCircleFill size={30} />
              ) : (
                <BsFilterCircle size={30} />
              )}
            </div>
            <div className={"filter__header__h3"}>FILTER</div>

            <div className={"filter__header__reset"} onClick={resetHandle}>
              <TfiReload color="blue" fontWeight={600} />
            </div>
            <div
              className={
                openFilter
                  ? "filter__header__price filter__header__price--open animate__animated animate__bounceInDown"
                  : "filter__header__price"
              }
            >
              <div
                className={
                  openFilter ? "animate__animated animate__bounceInDown" : ""
                }
              >
                <div
                  className={
                    priceOpened
                      ? "price__select-container price-open "
                      : "price__select-container price-close"
                  }
                >
                  <select
                    onClick={() => setPriceOpened((prev) => !prev)}
                    onChange={handleSortChange}
                  >
                    <option value="">Sort </option>
                    <option value="low-to-high">Price: Low to High</option>
                    <option value="high-to-low">Price: High to Low</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              className={
                openFilter
                  ? "filter__header__search filter__header__search--open animate__animated animate__bounceInDown"
                  : "filter__header__search"
              }
              onChange={handleSearch}
            >
              <AiOutlineSearch size={22} color={"gray"} />

              <input
                defaultValue={queryParams.get("search") || ""}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search..."
              />
            </div>
            <div className="filter__header__sort">
              <div
                onClick={() => setProductsAlign(true)}
                className={
                  productsAlign
                    ? "filter__header__sort__column active"
                    : "filter__header__sort__column "
                }
              >
                <BsReverseListColumnsReverse />
              </div>
              <div
                onClick={() => setProductsAlign(false)}
                className={
                  !productsAlign
                    ? "filter__header__sort__row active"
                    : "filter__header__sort__row"
                }
              >
                <AiOutlineInsertRowAbove />
              </div>
            </div>

            {openFilter ? (
              <div className="filter__header__bar animate__animated animate__bounceInDown">
                <div className="container">
                  <h3 className="filter__header__bar__title">Category</h3>
                  <div
                    ref={filterCategory}
                    className="filter__header__bar__wrapper"
                  >
                    {productTypes?.length > 0 ? (
                      productTypes.map((product, key) => {
                        return (
                          <Category
                            key={key}
                            setHref={setHref}
                            category={product.category}
                            types={product.types}
                          />
                        );
                      })
                    ) : (
                      <p style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                        We're sorry, but there are currently no categories{" "}
                        <BsEmojiFrown size={20} />
                      </p>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </div>

          <div className="filter__body">
            <div className="filter__body__leftbar">
              <h3 className="filter__body__leftbar__title">Categories</h3>

              {productTypes?.length > 0 ? (
                productTypes?.map((product, key) => {
                  return (
                    <Category
                      key={key}
                      setHref={setHref}
                      category={product.category}
                      types={product.types}
                    />
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                <p style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                  We're sorry, but there are currently no categories{" "}
                  <BsEmojiFrown size={20} />
                </p>
              )}
            </div>
            <div
              className={
                productsAlign
                  ? "filter__body__main filter__body__main--align"
                  : "filter__body__main"
              }
            >
              {currentProducts?.length > 0 ? (
                currentProducts?.map((product, i) => {
                  return (
                    <Product
                      key={i}
                      id={product.node.id}
                      title={product.node.title}
                      description={product.node.description}
                      type={product.node.productType}
                      creator={product.node.tags}
                      createdAt={product.node.createdAt}
                      sku={product.node.variants.edges[0].node.sku}
                      price={product.node.variants.edges[0].node.priceV2.amount}
                      img={
                        product.node.variants.edges[0].node.image.originalSrc
                      }
                      reviews={reviewData}
                      myProduct={user?.email === product.node.tags[0]}
                      variantId={product.node.variants.edges[0].node.id}
                    />
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                <div style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}>
                  {currentProducts?.length === 0 ? (
                    <h3>
                      {" "}
                      There are no such products with that title here{" "}
                      <BsEmojiFrown size={40} />
                    </h3>
                  ) : (
                    <Loader />
                  )}
                </div>
              )}

              {currentProducts?.length !== 0 && (
                <Pagination
                  currentPage={currentPage}
                  itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
                  totalItems={products?.length}
                  onPageChange={handlePageChange}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FilterContainer;
```

products.js (file from where `fetchProducts()` comes from)

```
import { updateLoader } from "../../redux/features/apiSlice";
import axios from "axios";

export const BASE_URL =
  "https://c97663-2.myshopify.com/api/2023-01/graphql.json";
export const ACCESS_TOKEN = "07a059546dee3d048794dc7744f6183a";

export const fetchProducts = async (dispatch, setProducts, setProductsData) => {
  try {
    dispatch(updateLoader(true));

    const query = `
      query {
        products(first: 250) {
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
          }
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
              description
              productType
              tags
              availableForSale
              createdAt
              variants(first: 1) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    sku
                    title
                    priceV2 {
                      amount
                      currencyCode
                    }
                    image {
                      originalSrc
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    const response = await axios.post(
      BASE_URL,
      { query },
      {
        headers: {
          "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    dispatch(updateLoader(false));

    const data = response.data.data;
    // setProducts(data.products.edges);
    setProductsData(data.products.edges);
    console.log(data.products.edges);
    return data.products.edges;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error fetching products: ${error.message}`);
    dispatch(updateLoader(false));
    throw error;
  }
};

export const fetchProduct = async (dispatch, id) => {
  try {
    dispatch(updateLoader(true));

    const query = `
      query getProductById($id: ID!) {
        product(id: $id) {
          id
          title
          description
          productType
          tags
          availableForSale
          createdAt
          images(first: 5) {
            edges {
              node {
                originalSrc
              }
            }
          }
          variants(first: 1) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                sku
                title
                priceV2 {
                  amount
                  currencyCode
                }
                image {
                  originalSrc
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    const variables = { id };

    const response = await axios.post(
      BASE_URL,
      { query, variables },
      {
        headers: {
          "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    dispatch(updateLoader(false));

    const data = response.data.data;
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error fetching product: ${error.message}`);
    dispatch(updateLoader(false));
    throw error;
  }
};
```

I tried everything; I tried to put `setstates` in `useEffect` then in  the end I put it in the products function, and still same result, I don't understand. Please help..